# How do I get the value between the start and end tag Python Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the value from this HTML tag automatically:

```html
<span data-testid="TemperatureValue" class="CurrentConditions--tempValue--1RYJJ">84°</span>
```

The temperature value in the middle changes automatically.

Also, should I be using the XPath or the full Xpath for my find_element_by_xpath() variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
degree = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-testid='TemperatureValue']").text

print(degree)
```

Comment: It says that there is no getAttribute() method

Comment: can you check it now

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[data-testid="TemperatureValue"]').text
```

Store this in a variable and print it